# How to avoid (or solve) unique constraint violation when inserting to db?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a partial unique constraint where a costumer_id can only have one is_primary flag set to True.

The behavior that I would like to achieve is: when I insert a row with is_primary=True and a customer_id that already has a is_primary flag set to True in the db, I would like to set that old entry to is_primary=False, and the new entry would be inserted with is_primary=True, not raising an IntegrityError.

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy with a postgresql db, is there any mechanism to do this easily or do I need to do it manually, first update old entry and then insert the new row?

```
class Customer_address(db.Model):
    customer_id = db.Column(None, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
    is_primary = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
                Index(
                    'only_one_primary_address',  # Index name
                    'customer_id',  # Columns which are part of the index
                    unique=True,
                    postgresql_where=(is_primary)  # The condition
                ),)
```

Comment: I think you need to reset `is_primary` on the current primary record manually.  I don't think there's a way to update an existing  record _and_ insert  using `ON CONFLICT` in a single operation.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Would a trigger on the table be a possible solution?

Comment: Yes the point of `ON CONFLICT`  is do either an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` or nothing. It won't do two operations at the same time. I believe it would be possible to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Basically test whether an existing `customer_id` record with `is_primary = 't'` exists, `UPDATE` that to `'f'` and then pass through the `NEW` record. This would require some testing. The same process could be done outside a trigger function in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it isn't a single database operation that will insert a new record and update the existing records, we can create an [event listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) in SQLAlchemy to listen for new address insertions and perform the updates.  This is conceptually similar to using a database trigger as discussed in the comments, except that it happens in SQLALchemy ORM sessions.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

@sa.event.listens_for(Customer_address, 'before_insert')
def receive_init(mapper, connection, target):
    """Listen for the insertion of new customer addresses."""
    # Get the active session 
    session = orm.session.object_session(target)
    cls = target.__class__
    # Update the existing is_primary == True record for this customer
    session.query(cls).filter(sa.and_(cls.customer_id == target.customer_id,
                                      cls.is_primary)).update({'is_primary': False}, synchronize_session='fetch')
```

A [Query.update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update), as performed in the listener bypasses ORM machinery, so it's worth reading the warnings associated with it in the docs.  In this case setting `synchronize_session` to `'fetch'` keeps the database and session in synch at the cost of issuing an extra `SELECT`, so we get a sequence of events like this:

```
2020-11-22 09:04:26,565 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT customer_address.id AS customer_address_id                 
FROM customer_address                                                                                                        
WHERE customer_address.customer_id = %(customer_id_1)s AND customer_address.is_primary                                       
2020-11-22 09:04:26,565 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'customer_id_1': 1}                                              
2020-11-22 09:04:26,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE customer_address SET is_primary=%(is_primary)s WHERE customer_address.customer_id = %(customer_id_1)s AND customer_address.is_primary                                                   
2020-11-22 09:04:26,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'is_primary': False, 'customer_id_1': 1}                         
2020-11-22 09:04:26,567 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO customer_address (customer_id, is_primary) VALUES (%(customer_id)s, %(is_primary)s) RETURNING customer_address.id                                                                  
2020-11-22 09:04:26,567 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'customer_id': 1, 'is_primary': True}                            
2020-11-22 09:04:26,568 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Note also that this approach doesn't work if you create multiple addresses for the customer at once:

```py
# Will violate the constraint
for _ in range(5):
    session.add(Customer_address(customer_id=1, is_primary=True))
session.commit()
```

If this is something that is likely to happen in you code, you could consider listening for [events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#) on the customer's address collection or on the address instance instead.

Comment: This is what I need but your example has a little problem. If the new record to be inserted has is_primary = 'f', the listener will still set the old entry to false. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: You can check the value of `target.is_primary` in the listener, and `return` before doing the update if it's `False` (or `None`).

Comment: Note a database-level trigger would also work, I'm just not familiar enough with the syntax to include it in the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm not familiar with triggers either, so this will do it for now. Thank you.